# Changing the default button (IsDefault) based on viewmodel state

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a dialog with one query TextBox and four Buttons.
Depending on the result of the query one or more of the buttons are enabled.
The TextBox is bound to a property on the VM and each of the buttons are bound to Commands on the VM

Command.IsEnabled changes based on QueryResult

```
class ViewModel
{
  public string Query {get;set;}
  public QueryResult QueryResult {get;set;}
  public ICommand FooCommand {get;set;}
  public ICommand BarCommand {get;set;}
  public ICommand BazCommand {get;set;}
  public ICommand QuxCommand {get;set;}
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding Query, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding FooCommand}" Content="Foo"/>
<Button Command="{Binding BarCommand}" Content="Bar"/>
<Button Command="{Binding BazCommand}" Content="Baz"/>
<Button Command="{Binding QuxCommand}" Content="Qux"/>
```

There is additional logic to determine which of the enabled buttons should be the default (visibly highlighted and activated when pressing enter)

(Foo is always enabled, Bar is enabled if QueryResult.A is non-null, Baz is enabled if QueryResult.B is non-null etc. Multiple commands can be enabled, but there is a fixed prioritized order of preference that determines the default action)

Bar > Baz > Foo > Qux

My problem is how to bind the Button.IsDefault on the buttons to reflect which one should be default.

I've thought of the following options - neither of which seems right

1. Create an enum property {btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4} DefaultButton on the VM. Bind each buttons IsDefault property to this with a converter that compares its parameter to the current value
2. Create four boolean properties on the VM IsButton1Default etc... and bind to these
3. Something with styles+datatriggers but that makes my XAML difficult to comprehend.

What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

i would choose number 2, because i dont like converters for this kind of logic. its also easy to unittest and more easy to understand and implement :)